# XSLT: attribute sorting

Tags: xslt, sorting, attributes, tags

I need help with a small example, so that I can understand `xsl:sort` better.

My XML data looks like:

```
<NewTerms>
    <newTerm ID="3">Zebra</newTerm>
    <newTerm ID="11">Horse</newTerm>
    <newTerm ID="1">Cat</newTerm>
    <newTerm ID="90">Lion</newTerm>
    <newTerm ID="62">Jaguar</newTerm>
    <newTerm ID="30">Cheetah</newTerm>
    <newTerm ID="55">Deer</newTerm>
    <newTerm ID="45">Buffalo</newTerm>
    <newTerm ID="15">Dog</newTerm>
</NewTerms ID="10">
```

and I want to sort them according to the `ID` attribute. The XSL that I have is not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(preceding::node()=.)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(preceding::node()=.)]">
                <xsl:sort select="./@ID"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't know how the `xsl:sort` function works. Help me through this example to get a better understanding of it.

Comment: Nice to see an attribute in an [End-Tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#NT-ETag) :D

Comment: +1 basic but useful question.

Answer (score 4):

Your transform is **correct**. You have missed only to specify the `data-type` attribute which by default is "text" thus not working with numbers.

For more information about using `xsl:sort` you can see the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-sort) and a recent similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389486/how-can-i-sort-elements-by-new-counted-values-in-their-child-element-xslt-1-0/6391812#6391812).

Here a few notes:

- You can omit the `./@ID` because `.` selects the context node which is the default in the template
- You don't need to check for preceding nodes in that way, it does not make sense.

**Notice** You need only the [**Identity Transformation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#d5e17557) with a sort instruction.

Your final transform will look like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="@ID" data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the input (here a bit modified to fix your end-tag typo):

```
<NewTerms>   
    <newTerm ID="3">Zebra</newTerm>
    <newTerm ID="11">Horse</newTerm> 
    <newTerm ID="1">Cat</newTerm>   
    <newTerm ID="90">Lion</newTerm>   
    <newTerm ID="62">Jaguar</newTerm>   
    <newTerm ID="30">Cheetah</newTerm>   
    <newTerm ID="55">Deer</newTerm>   
    <newTerm ID="45">Buffalo</newTerm>   
    <newTerm ID="15">Dog</newTerm> 
</NewTerms>
```

produces:

```
<NewTerms>
   <newTerm ID="1">Cat</newTerm>
   <newTerm ID="3">Zebra</newTerm>
   <newTerm ID="11">Horse</newTerm>
   <newTerm ID="15">Dog</newTerm>
   <newTerm ID="30">Cheetah</newTerm>
   <newTerm ID="45">Buffalo</newTerm>
   <newTerm ID="55">Deer</newTerm>
   <newTerm ID="62">Jaguar</newTerm>
   <newTerm ID="90">Lion</newTerm>
</NewTerms>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ID` attribute in your clasing tag of NewTerms seems to be out of place.

The following XSL script sorts your data on the `ID` attribute:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/NewTerms">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="newTerm">
        <xsl:sort select="@ID" data-type="number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Those ID attribute values look like numbers so doing '<xsl:sort select="@ID" data-type="number"/>` is probably necessary to sort as requested. The default data type is "text" and that way for instance "110" would end up before "12".

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments to @rsp's answer, the [default sort `data-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-sort) is "text", but you want "number". You could actually use your own first attempt after making just that one change:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(preceding::node()=.)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(preceding::node()=.)]">
        <xsl:sort select="./@ID" data-type="number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This allows you to keep your (inefficient) duplicate check:

```
node()[not(preceding::node()=.)]
```